# EntityFramework Multiple Queries Multiple DataContexts? Multiple Connections?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm new to EF, and for the first time I need to execute multiple queries in the same time, lets say I have my BLL and DAL generated by EF, I also have a viewModel, on the BLL I'm referencing DAL and retrieve data like this:

```
public Decimal getPrice()
    {
        Decimal x = 0;
        siliconContext = new DAL.Entities();
        var result = from d in siliconContext.SILICONs
                     select d.MIN_PRICE;
        foreach (Decimal d in result)
        {
            x = d;
        }
        return x;
    }
```

all good, on the viewModel I use just this two lines of code:

```
Silicon sil = new Silicon();
Price = sil.getPrice();
```

I assumed that the Context will handle the connection, open the connection, do something and then close it, but now I'm in a situation where in my ViewModel I will reference two BLLs which they are going to reference two DALs and of course two different Contexts in the same method, who is going to manage this? is EF 4 is smart enough to open only one connection and let the two - or more - contexts to do their job and then close the connection? here is an example of how my viewModel will look like

```
Silicon sil = new Silicon();
Price = sil.getPrice();
Glass gl = new Glass();
GlassPrice = gl.getPrice();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you need to close the connection of the DataContext.

```
public Decimal getPrice()
{
    Decimal x = 0;
    using (DAL.Entities siliconContext = new DAL.Entities())
    {
        var result = from d in siliconContext.SILICONs
                     select d.MIN_PRICE;
        foreach (Decimal d in result)
        {
            x = d;
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

Secondly if you want to get data from two tables then do the following.

```
public Decimal getPrice()
{
    Decimal x = 0; 
    using (DAL.Entities siliconContext = new DAL.Entities())
    {
        var result = from d in siliconContext.SILICONs
                     select d.MIN_PRICE;

        var result2 = from d in seliconContext.GLASEs
                      select d.MIN_PRICE;

        //You can then work with results from table GLASE!

        foreach (Decimal d in result)
        {
            x = d;
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , I only have one database , in my example I'm trying to retrieve from  two tables , Silicon and Glass , I understood your first code snippet , the second however doesn't reply my questions , are you saying for only one database and multible tables I will still use one context ? , how can I do that then ? to accomplish my last code snippet ?

Comment: agree, I understood something new now, but still please see the last code in my post , I have two different classes(Silicon and Glass) , every class will reference it's DAL class and every DAL class will connect to database on his own ,because every class will execute it's own getPrice() method, thats means two different connections, conections will open and close one after another , for perfromance sake thats is not good , I guess this is a design issue but I'm not sure , I hope you got my point

Comment: Yes, you are bit worried about preformace with always opening and closing the connection to the database. I personlly prefer this method where the life of the connection is only "alive" for that specifiy unit of work so to say. I wouldn't be too concerned about the performance. Also Ragzitsu showed a really good link that will help explain most the questions you have. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to manage the lifetime of your objectcontext for their proper initialization and disposal. For an excellent resource on context lifetime management, refer to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/05/07/tip-18-how-to-decide-on-a-lifetime-for-your-objectcontext.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link , going to see it in a while